# Upload file through salesforce community login

Tags: file-upload, salesforce, salesforce-communities

I want to upload file in salesforce community portal. I have took reference [Upload multiple file](https://sfdclesson.com/2019/06/15/upload-multiple-files-through-visualforce-page/) for uploading files. It's working fine while executing as system admin user but while I am trying to execute same thing with salesforce community user login it's give error. Data was not Uploaded in "contentversion" table.

Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

The first thing to check is to make sure the Salesforce license assigned to that user has access to "Files", not just notes and attachments:

https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.users_license_types_communities.htm&type=5

According to the document, Files aren't available to Customer Community Licenses and Lightning External Apps licenses.

Answer (score 0):

You can use File Upload Improved from Unofficialsf. It allows community users to upload files to records that they don’t necessarily have access to.

https://unofficialsf.com/from-josh-dayment-improved-file-upload-in-flow-screens/